# “Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.”

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to update the field in a Sharepoint Discussion board using the Client Object Model in C#.  When the code reaches the `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` it throws exception as:

`Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.`

Here is the part of code:

```
foreach (var field in newItemProperties)
{
    if (field.Key.Equals("ContentType"))
        continue;

    if (ctFields == null)
        spItem[field.Key] = field.Value;

    else
    {
        bool foundField = false;
        foreach (var fieldCT in ctFields)
        {
            fieldCT.ReadOnlyField=false;
            if (fieldCT.InternalName == field.Key)
            {
                foundField = true;
                if (isAllDayEvent)
                {
                    if (field.Key == "EventDate")
                    {
                        // For all day event, Add 10 hour in order to prevent the EventDate to be decreased by 1 day
                        var dateVal = (DateTime)field.Value;
                        // spItem[field.Key] = dateVal.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
                    }
                    else if (field.Key == "EndDate")
                    {
                        // For all day event, Subtract 10 hour in order to prevent the EndDate to be increased by 1 day
                        var dt = (DateTime)field.Value;
                        // spItem[field.Key] = dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
                    }
                    else
                        spItem[field.Key] = field.Value;

                }
                else
                    spItem[field.Key] = field.Value;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!foundField)
        {
            // Update the item properties values even its not part of CT
            // MM hidden fields are not part of CT fields
            if (isAllDayEvent)
            {
                if (field.Key == "EventDate")
                {
                    // For all day event, Add 10 hour in order to prevent the EventDate to be decreased by 1 day
                    var dateVal = (DateTime)field.Value;
                    //spItem[field.Key] = dateVal.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
                }
                else if (field.Key == "EndDate")
                {
                    // For all day event, Subtract 10 hour in order to prevent the EndDate to be increased by 1 day
                    var dt = (DateTime)field.Value;
                    //spItem[field.Key] = dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0, 0));
                }
                else
                    spItem[field.Key] = field.Value;

            }
            else
                spItem[field.Key] = field.Value;
        }
    }
}

spItem.Update();            
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting my answer here in case people find this question by googling the error message that in the title of this SO question.  This answer might help others who come across this strange error message.

I had the same error when I was updating a calendar event with server side code.

My code first added a new empty list item.  This new list item has default values for the start date and end date.  A few lines later, the list item fields are updated one by one (similar to the op code) and then a list item `update` is called.  In my case, the start date was not being updated by my code and remained the default value.  The end date got updated by my code and the end date was earlier in time than the default start date.  When the list item `update` was fired, this error would be displayed in my exception logs.

Once I corrected this and adjusted the start date to always fall *before* the end date and then call `update`, the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery caml = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery();

caml.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='File'>" + itemname+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";



caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = relativepath;



Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(caml);


clientContext.Load(items);

clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password","domain");


clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


if (items.Count > 0){item["attribute"]=value;}
```